# I can't get my width to expand

Tags: html, css

I am fairly comfortable with css and html, but I can't get the width of a div to expand.  I have tried using !important to over ride anything else, but it isn't working.

CSS

```
  .LR-site-description{
    color:#fff;
    font-size:26px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-shadow: 4px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    width:900px !important;
    text-align:center;
```

}

HTML

```
  <div class="LR-site-description montserrat" style="width:600px">
                            <p>How would a friend describe what you are working on? Sometimes being vague.</p>
  </div>
```

So I have the width in both of these because I was trying to get it to work in both the CSS and with the style.  On the actual site,  treerings.co  ,the second paragraph won't expand past 300px.  I am using a launchrock template, but it gives one full customization.  Any help would be great I have been working on this for that few hours :-(

Comment: in video.css, line 174, there's a max-width..

Comment: … which you could’ve found out yourself easily looking at the applied styles in your browser’s developer tools.

Comment: I was using firebug and it didn't show it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, on the website treerings you actually have a width of 360px, which comes from a line saying `max-width: 360px;` So just add `max-width: none !important;` to your style to override the property

Comment: Awesome thanks.  Their template thing, doesn't allow you to see their current CSS.  How did you guys see that max-width thing?